# How to use React app as add-on plugin in Php project

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, plugins

I have a single page React app and want to use it as add-on plugin in my other existing PHP based projects just like we add use any chatbot plugins using script tag.

I want to show it as a popup modal. I'm wondering how can i achieve this.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have two different apps. The main app is made with PHP and the chatbot is made in React, and you want to display the chatbot in a popup modal. Is that correct?